# C# EF6 Groupjoin on stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I try to do a GroupJoin on a stored procedure with entity framework 6.
This group join is working on Entity but on stored procedure I get an exception with this message :

> "An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details." and inner exception "The nested query does not have the appropriate keys.".

My stored procedure key is a `Nullable` int but I specified that `Entity Framework` need to use key.Value.

I don't understand where is the problem.

```
var test = contextEF.MyStoredProcedur(varInt)
.GroupJoin(contextEF.LinkedEntity, p => p.EntityId.Value, s => s.EntityId, (p, s) => new { p = p, s = s.ToList() }).ToList();

var test2 = contextEF.MyEntity
.GroupJoin(contextEF.LinkedEntity, p => p.EntityId.Value, s => s.EntityId, (p, s) => new { p = p, s = s.ToList() }).ToList();
```

test is not working. test2 is working

Comment: show some code!

Comment: you cannot do it in this way, try `contextEF.LinkedEntity.ToList()`

Comment: Yes I know, but I want to do this with only one request. I can do this in multiple requests easily.